# ADFS claims rule iterate AD attribute

Tags: adfs, claims-authentication

How do I iterate an AD attribute as a claims rule in ADFS?

More specifically, I'd like to check whether the user's proxyAddresses contains a predetermined domain, and if so, return that email as Name ID, else the the user's main email.

Answer (score 0):

You would use [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/askds/ad-fs-2-0-claims-rule-language-part-2) on the claims rule to check for the domain and if there, issue the NameID claim.

Then use a "[NOT EXISTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/askds/ad-fs-2-0-claims-rule-language-primer)" rule.

So something like:

```
NOT EXISTS([Type == "http://contoso.com/NAMID"])
=> add(Type = "http://contoso.com/hasNAMEID", Value = "No");

Sample Rule 2:

c1:[Type == "http://contoso.com/hasNameID"] &&
c2:[Type == "http://contoso.com/email"]
=> issue(Type="http://contoso.com/email", Value=c2.value);
```

Using the normal email claim type etc.

And about 10 minutes after writing this, I found this example that shows the solution in [more detail](https://jorgequestforknowledge.wordpress.com/category/active-directory-federation-services-adfs/claims-rule-language/).

Comment: Thanks. I actually managed to get things working myself, so my own comment.

Answer (score 0):

I played around a bit yesterday, and ended up with the following, which seems to work, but perhaps not the cleanest way?

Rule #1:

Regular attribute claim for Proxy-Addresses and User-Principal-Name

Rule #2:

```
c:[Type == "fake/proxyAddresses", Value =~ "subdomain.example.com$"]
 => issue(Type = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier", Value = RegExReplace(c.Value, "smtp:", ""));
```

Rule #3:

```
NOT EXISTS([Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier"])
 => add(Type = "fake/UseUPN", Value = "Yes");
```

Rule #4:

```
c1:[Type == "fake/UseUPN"]
 && c2:[Type == "fake/UPN"]
 => issue(Type = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier", Value = c2.Value);
```